# sending button using facebook messenger in php

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to send a button attachment using facebook messenger bot.

I trided it using  javascript  and it works fine, but php it does not.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
     $button1= array("type"=>"postback","title"=>"Click Button","payload"=>"something:") ;
     $buttons= array($button1);
     $payload=array("template_type"=>"button","text"=>"Something","buttons"=>$buttons);

     $attachment=array("type"=>"template","payload"=>$payload);

     $messageData= array("recipient"=>"xxxxxxxxxx",
                         "message"=>array("attachment"=>$attachment));


     $data= json_encode($messageData);
     callSendAPI($data);
```

error message is

```
          {"error":{"message":"(#100) param recipient must be non-empty.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"DZN+n5S7uuR"}}
```

Nothing wrong with  callSendAPI() function , because it works with text, image messages.

What am I doing wrong here???

Thanks

Comment: you should add the javascript version that works too

Comment: its facebook documnetaion code

Comment: I think this is something wrong with my php json object

Comment: ok. I forgot to add "recipient" value as an array.

Comment: does not matter if it´s in the docs, you should at least add the link then. alyways add as much information as possible.

Comment: Hi mota bul I need how u have u done in jquery or php please help me if you can

Comment: @sunil can you explain your problem ?

Comment: @motabul i need a code of sending message i have only page access token but its not working using curl

Comment: $t='EZD';
$data = '{"recipient":{"id":"628134014"},"message":{"text":"h!"}}';
        $ch = curl_init("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=$t");
        $header=array('Content-Type: application/json');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

Comment: this is my token EAACW5Fg5N2IBAAoEZAHyDspz0xMSLkZBdBc8PS5QGl3Y8iZCpHTD71pJCzOEndq3ZBsnDU0QSqe07v7pxDln8uig4O3Hgw4KeyoJqs9eOHf6wGXlysHO1VrC3SON4NvUNUY1pkLwZAFbuc0TO8fcS9NUwihIQg1X7eCxcsq4RGlLjJGJryiDdTyPtBaQhdDkSz3jRUUyHMgZDZD